# How to apply CSS changes in every posts (every posts ID)

Tags: css, wordpress, posts

I want to hide the side bar and stretch the content box to full width to all posts from my WP blog. To individual posts that's what I'm doing, and it's working fine:

```
.postid-72 #main-sidebar {
display: none;
}
.postid-72 #main-content {
width: 100%;
}
```

But I'm looking for some way to apply this changes to all my blog posts, something hypothetical like this:

```
.postid-**every id posts** #main-sidebar {
display: none;
}
.postid-**every id posts** #main-content {
width: 100%;
}
```

I know that is possible to do something like this, which isn't usefull for me:

```
.postid-72, .postid-53, .postid-115 #main-sidebar {
display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Every "single post" has a body class of `single-post`. So you could just do:

```
.single-post #main-sidebar {
  display:none;
}
.single-post #main-content {
  width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add a common class to all post like `stretch-content`and use css like

```
.stretch-content #main-sidebar {
display: none;
}
.stretch-content #main-content {
width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for the CSS [Attribute Selector](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp). Specifically:

> The `[attribute^="value"]` selector is used to select elements whose attribute value begins with a specified value.

So to select any element with a class that starts with "postid-" you could use the following:

```
[class^="postid-"] #main-sidebar {
display: none;
}
[class^="postid-"] #main-content {
width: 100%;
}
```

Note the `^=`

This will select all elements that have a class beginning with the string inside the quotes. Leaving out the `^` would yield the same results as using `.postid-` as the selector.

Also note, while these selectors can be a very powerful addition to your CSS toolkit they can have their pitfalls. It becomes much easier to unintentionally select other elements; especially in the large ecosystem of WP plugins.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just set this two css by using post id then you can set only this two css in your `header.php` file inside `head` section with passing dynamic ID something like this:

First of all get current post id with : `$id = get_the_ID()` then pass it in your css using,

```
.postid-<?php echo $id; ?> #main-sidebar {
display: none;
}
.postid-<?php echo $id; ?> #main-content {
width: 100%;
}
```

Hope this will helpful for you.
Thanks.